# Registry pattern for Globals | Validation

Tags: javascript

For the code below, I want to use module pattern to keep the members private and access them through a getter.  It is so simple there is no need to put any initialization in the constructor.  Is this O.K?

```
/**
 *Global - in process of removing
 */

var Globals = ( function () 
{
    var globals = 
    {
        tag_array:          [],
        load_on:            0,
        current_tag:        0,             
        TIME:               4000,
        PASS:               0,
        FAIL:               1,
        NOTDEFINED:         2
    };
    var GlobalsInternal = function ( ) 
    {
    };
    GlobalsInternal.prototype.get = function( type ) 
    {
        return globals[ type ];
    };
    return GlobalsInternal;
} () );
```

**Use**

```
new Globals().get( 'TIME' );
```

Comment: More info on Javascript constructors here: http://pivotallabs.com/users/pjaros/blog/articles/1368-javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword

Comment: @The All Foo: just an FYI -- your use case will not work...it looks like you've omitted the parenthesis.  It should read: new Globals().get('Time');

Comment: @ajax81 Good call. `(new Globals).get('Time')` would also work. `new` has funny handling of parenthesis.

Comment: Why explicitly include a parameter (element) in the constructor when It doesn't get used?

Comment: @nnnnnn It is because `new Globals.get('TIME')` is equivalent to `new (Globals.get)('TIME')`. It is treated as `new expression(argumentList)`, where `(argumentList)` is optional, but `expression` is greedy. (This is why the secondary form I posted would also work.)

Comment: @pst - I  understand what you and ajax81 were saying. I was talking about the param in the constructor declaration in the original version of the question, a parameter that has since been removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have classes.

So no constructor-function means no constructor-function and an empty constructor-function is still a constructor-function.

Thus, if `new X` is desired, then `X` *must* evaluate to a constructor-function (which is really just a function that knows how to behave in context).

In any case, that's "okay". Just keep in mind that there is only one object named by `globals` (and it is closed over in the `get` function with such a name).

---

(I think josh3736's answer has merit for just a "global dump". A globally-named object in JS *is* a singleton in other OO-language senses.)

Comment: Would a Javascript novice understand this?  Or only experts?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it depends on if one started on JavaScript or another "OO" language :-)

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with simply doing:

```
var Globals = {
        tag_array:          [],
        load_on:            0,
        current_tag:        0,             
        TIME:               4000,
        PASS:               0,
        FAIL:               1,
        NOTDEFINED:         2
    };
```

Then just

```
Globals.TIME
```

To be honest, your sample seems to unnecessarily complicate things and reeks of trying to impose classical OO onto JavaScript, *which isn't a classical OO language*.

Comment: JavaScript _is_ OO. It just isn't class-based OO.

Comment: @nnnnnn On the other hand, this is nice'n'simple so ... I have to give a +1 for "why not"? Granted it doesn't *particularly* answer the question ...

Comment: @nnnnnn, "classical" OO.  Sure JS supports certain aspects of OO, but it does omit others -- classes, encapsulation (private members), and (classical, typed) inheritance to name a few; and polymorphism is implicit rather than explicit.

Comment: @The All Foo, your comment has disappeared (*"This is what I'm doing now, I'm updating my code"*), but I wanted to respond anyway: How is this an improvement?  From the perspective of someone new to a codebase, `new Globals().get('TIME')` is harder to read and understand than a simple `Globals.TIME`.  (Does `Globals()` have side effects?  Now I have to find it...)  Plus, it minifies worse and is less efficient.  (And don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be insulting; I'm just trying to say that this might be an attempt to apply a pattern that is mismatched to the language.)